# f in C[a,b]. Show there exists a sequence of polynomials that converges to f that are always less than f?

Tags: real-analysis, approximation-theory

Let f in C[a,b]. Show there exists a sequence of polynomials {p} such that (sup norm) ||p-f|| -> 0 for all n.

I think fixing g less than f and approximating that g with the polynomials is where to begin, but I don't see how to guarantee that the polynomials stay below f (or below g, for that matter). It looks like a Weierstrass Approximation Problem but I don't think it can be proved using that.

Comment: It is worth considering that the sequence of trigonometric polynomials given by $f*F_N$, where $F_N$ is the Fejér kernel, meet the wanted constraints since $F_N$ is a non-negative kernel. If there is some **polynomial** kernel sharing the same property, you are done.

Comment: Anyway, $p\leq f$ is not needed to grant $\|p-f\|_{\infty}\to 0$, I think you are over-complicating it.

Comment: "Let f in C[a,b]. Show there exists a sequence of polynomials {p} such that (sup norm) ||p-f|| -> 0 for all n." ??? That's exactly what Weierstrass gives you.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Consider the function
\begin{align}
f_n(x) = f(x) -\frac{1}{n} 
\end{align}
then by Weierstrass approximation theorem there exists a polynomial, call it $P_n(x)$, such that
\begin{align}
\|P_n(x) - f_n(x)\|_\infty <\frac{1}{n}
\end{align}
which mean
\begin{align}
f(x)-P_n(x) = f(x)-\frac{1}{n}-P_n(x) + \frac{1}{n}>-\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n}=0.
\end{align}
Let $n\rightarrow \infty$, then you will have your desired result.